# Is there any way to export variables in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am doing app where i check image size, make ratio calculation of that, because height in pdf must be always 100px, width can be changed and i change it depengin ratio of original picture.

I am tried to export const variable to different component. But it gives me Syntax error for `export { imageHeight };` and `export { imageWidth };` also. How can I do this import in react-native? This should work in react. I can not use export default, because I have it already.

Camera component:

```
Image.getSize(data.uri, (width, height) => { // KOODI TOIMII ja hakee tiedot
            let imageWidth = width;
            let imageHeight = height;
            
            console.log(`The image dimensions are ${imageWidth}x${imageHeight}`);
          }, (error) => {
            console.error(`Couldn't get the image size: ${error.message}`);
          });

export { imageHeight };
export { imageWidth};
```

Then, I have a pdf creating component:

```
import { imageHeight, imageWidth } from './Camera';

const pdfHeight = 100;
const ratio = imageHeight/imageWidth; // example 1200/1600=0,75

page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
                    x: imgX,
                    y: imgY,
                    width: pdfHeight/ratio,
                    height: pdfHeight,
                })
```

Comment: Hi @Joko Joko, There is a old answer regarding this. Have a look on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280777/how-to-export-variables-to-separate-file-react-native. This will answer your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cant export a nameless JSON file.
2. You cant use let defined variables out of the scope
3. You can export using `export default variableName` or `export variableName`

   ```
   const {imageWidth, imageHeight} = Image.getSize(data.uri, (width, height) => {
           let imageWidth = width;
           let imageHeight = height;

           console.log(`The image dimensions are ${imageWidth}x${imageHeight}`);
         return {imageWidth, imageHeight}
         }, (error) => {
           console.error(`Couldn't get the image size: ${error.message}`);
         });

   export imageHeight;
   export imageWidth;
   ```

   and

   ```
   import { imageHeight, imageWidth } from './Camera';
   const pdfHeight = 100;
   const ratio = imageHeight/imageWidth; // example 1200/1600=0,75

   page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
        x: imgX,
        y: imgY,
        width: pdfHeight/ratio,
        height: pdfHeight,
   })
   ```